# How to work with the symbol EndOfFile?

Tags: expression-test

How to work with the symbol `EndOfFile`? I want to use the `EndOfFile` symbol to determine when my control structure reaches the end of a file.

Case 1: suppose we reach the end of file while continuously reading numbers from it. `Which` correctly returns `"end"`.

```
num=EndOfFile;
Which[
  num==EndOfFile, res="end",
  num==1,         res="1",
  num==2,         res="2",
  True,           res="non"
]

(* ==> "end" *)
```

Case 2: suppose we read a 3 (that is, `num=3`): in this case `Which` returns unevaluated.

Comment: When you compare nonnumerical values, you should always use `SameQ` (`===`) to test for structural identity instead of numerical equation (`Equal` = `==`). `EndOfFile` does not have a numerical value thus if `num` is 1, `1 == EndOfFile` returns unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Which[num === EndOfFile, res = "end", 
      num == 1,          res = "1", 
      num == 2,          res = "2", 
      True,              res = "non"]
```

**Edit**

Perhaps you may want to experiment a little with `SameQ[]`. For example:

```
ClearAll[h, j]
h == j
h === j
(*
 h == j
 False
*)
```